# Relation to Mutliple Table with condtion

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

i have 3 tables

```
1.Testcase : id 

2.sceanrio : id, testcaseId

3.test case step: id testcase id,sceanrio id
```

I m trying to make relationship for these table based on following condtion

if test case has sceanrio then it should chilr of Testcase  and test case step should be child of scenario or else test case step should child of test case

As per my knowledge i never seen condition based relation like this .i know has many through but i cant apply in this condtion can any one help me how i can achieve this

Has Many Through
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships
as per laravel documentation my tables are not related like has many through

Answer (score 1):

You can make relationship like this:-

```
Testcase Model 
public function getsceanrio(){
    return $this->hasMany('APP\sceanrio','testcaseId','id')->with('gettestcasestep');
}

public function testcasestepGet(){
    return $this->hasMany('APP\TestCaseStep','testcase_id','id');
}     

Now in sceanrio Model
 public function gettestcasestep(){
    return $this->hasMany('APP\TestCaseStep','sceanrio_id','id');
}
```

Now in controller

```
Public function someNameofFunction(){
   $getdata = TestCase::with('getsceanrio','testcasestepGet')->get();
   dd($getdata);
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: @kunal.Thanks but how can i give condtion if scenario not there for test cases.if i use your method then testcases wont appear if scenario not there

Comment: yes if sceanrio  is not there then what type of functionality you want ? i am not understand

Comment: i mean in some test cases scenario will not be there but test case step will be there